# How to share a structure array in all process?

Tags: c, mpi

I have a structure, it may look like

```c
typedef struct {
    char *data;
    int length;
} string;
```

then I define a array

```c
string *my_data = (string *)malloc(sizeof(string) * 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  my_data[i].data = strdup(other_str);
  my_data[i].length = strlen(other_str);
}
```

I want to broadcast the array to all process, but I don't know how to do this. All data will read from the files, so I can't change `char *data` to `char data[MAX_LEN]`, if here are some good methods? Thanks a lot!

I found that the MPI have the shared memory, so I try to use shared memory, but also got the `Signal: Segmentation fault (11)`

Comment: Does it have to be processes? It's rather easy to share data between threads within a single process.

Comment: The easiest approach is to broadcast `length` first, and then the `length MPI_CHAR`. You can also consider having all the processes read the file with `MPI_File_read_all`.

Comment: The scale of the problem is very large, I want to do this in many nodes, but it even doesn't work in one node:( @TedLyngmo

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a beginner of mpi, so I want to know if I use `MPI_File_read_all`, can all processor get the file pointer? And the data can be shared in all process? I search the network just now, but don't find the relative comments.@GillesGouaillardet

Comment: I do not what you mean by "get the file pointer". according to https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_File_read_all.html, this is a "Collective read using individual file pointer". This is logically equivalent to all processes opening and reading the same file independently, but you let  the MPI library figure out how to optimize that for you.

Comment: OK, I know! Thank you very much!@GillesGouaillardet